# How to get all the iframes in a page

Tags: html, iframe, selenium

I have a very complex html page.

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
<iframe> A </iframe>
  <table>
   <div>
    <span>
      <div> <iframe> B </iframe> </div>
        <style>
          <div>
            <div>
```

When I try to locate an element in the iframe A it is getting to another iframe. I tried switching to the iframe using driver.switchTo().frame(0) but no use.

When I try to get all the iframes using the findElements method it is returning only one iframe (B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what you want to do with the list of iframes.

If you want all the list, you can try using recursive function.

```
public void getAlliFrames(){
   List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));

   if(iframe.count() > 0){
      driver.switchTo().frame(iframe.get(0));

      getAlliFrames();
   }else{
      System.out.println("No more iframes");
   }
}
```

PS: This is an untested code and just provided for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your advise...I figured it out and now I can go further.. :)